# (BEGINNER) JAVA do...while loop logic broken?

Tags: java, loops

In the code bellow I make a do..while loop that is supposed to repeat if the value is between 1000 and 9999, but the logic of the do..while loop seems off.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Nal2 {
public static void main(String[] ARGS) {
    int i = 0;
    Scanner bralnik = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.printf("Insert a 4 digit num: ");
        i = bralnik.nextInt();
    } while (i >= 1000 && i <= 9999);

    System.out.print("Oi");
  }
}
```

This dosen't work but the code bellow works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Nal2 {
public static void main(String[] ARGS) {
    int i = 0;
    Scanner bralnik = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.printf("Insert a 4 digit num: ");
        i = bralnik.nextInt();

    } while (i <= 1000 || i >= 9999);

    System.out.print("Oi");
 }
}
```

Shouldn the `&&` works instead of the `||`?

I'm really confused about this.

I'm using InteliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 CE

Comment: Other than the edge cases of 1000 and 9999, your two loop conditions do the opposite of each other. The first loops as long as it's inside the range, and the second loops as long as it's outside. The IDE you're using has no impact on this.

Comment: Your first example works perfectly. It repeats as long as the number is within the range of 1,000 to 9,999. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner bralnik = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.printf("Insert a 4 digit num: ");
            i = bralnik.nextInt();


        } while (!(i<=1000||i>=9999));

        System.out.print("Oi");
    }
```

if you write code just with OR(||), you write above. ! is Logical not   Reverse the result, returns false if the result is true.
Your second snippet does not work because, you write OR, OR returns true if one of the conditions is true.